# Pandas Multiple String Columns to a List of Integers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` like this where both columns are `object`.

```
    +-----+--------------------+--------------------+
    |  id |         col1       |         col2       |
    +-----+--------------------+--------------------+
    |   1 |  0,1,4,0,1         |  1,2,4,0,0         |
    +-----+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I convert them into a list like this

```
test = df["col1"]+','+df["col2"]
test.tolist()
```

Which produces the following results as a SINGLE STING element in a list

```
['0,1,4,0,1,1,2,4,0,0']
```

However, I want them as a list of integers like this

```
[0,1,4,0,1,1,2,4,0,0]
```

Any suggestions? Just FYI, the columns are really huge in my original dataset so performance might be an issue too.

Comment: Do you have control over how those columns were created in the first place? If performance might be an issue that's the place to spend the effort.

Comment: They come from a CSV file.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want:

```
(df['col1'] + ',' + df['col2']).apply(lambda row: [int(s) for s in row.split(',')])
```

Output:

```
0    [0, 1, 4, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0]
dtype: object
```

Comment: How can I have it as a pure `list` instead of an object as the output goes to other functions to be processed?

Comment: does your dataframe have just one row?

Comment: Good question. I do have multiple rows but as a preprocess, I already make sure that there is one row comes in at a time. It would be better if the solution can handle multiple rows :-)

Comment: This solution gives you a series of lists, each for a row. So if you want to pass each list to your function, you can do a loop `for r in series: your_func(r)`, where `series` is the output above.

Answer (score 3):

another method using `str.split` and `explode`

```
arr = df.set_index('id').stack().str.split(',').explode().astype(int).values

print(arr)
array([0, 1, 4, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Encountered with this error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'`

Comment: @AbuShoeb what version of pandas are you on ? it was added in 0.25

Comment: I see. Mine is 0.23.4

Comment: @AbuShoeb if you can upgrade then do that otherwise you can use stack again after str.split with arg `expand=True`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with map as

```
 test = str(df["col1"]+','+df["col2"])
 list(map(int, test.split(',')))
```

Comment: As I mentioned in another answer, would it possible to have the final result as a list instead of map object?

Comment: Typecast the entire thing to list. Updated

Comment: I think I tried it before and tried again now and ended up with `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0    1'`